# uTorrent: invisible text torrent name column in Wine

Tags: wine, utorrent

Is there any solution/workaround for missing name text column on uTorrent 3.4.30635-1 under Wine 1.7.14-1 ?

i've tried to change preferences > advanced > sys.enable_wine_hacks, but it does nothing..

[image]

Comment: Not an answer of course, but do you know there are _many_ [native torrent clients](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent#Official_Ubuntu_Clients) for Linux?

Comment: I've tried Tixati (100% but file corrupted), Azureus and Transmission (most torrent corrupted when crashed), qTorrent (slow ui for thousands of torrent), rtorrent and ctorrent (not liking them), none of them as satisfying as uTorrent for Windows, i need rss downloader, labeling, auto-recheck when torrent already exists on download folder and complete folder, autoload from a folder..

Comment: ah nevermind, i'll just use the WebUI.. :3

Comment: If you need thousands of torrents you should really learn `rtorrent`, it is the one that uses the lesser amount of resources for notifications.  And notifications is what is killing your resources (i.e. making the system run slower).